# Hip-Hop PHP for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to achieve compiling Node.js scripts as native code, like Hip-Hop does for PHP?

I'm not talking about libraries/apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to pre-compile on your own. IIRC, in node, V8 compiles your js before it even runs a single line. So, where with PHP you're code is constantly being interpreted (unless you have some opcode caching in place), with node, you're code is compiled once when you start your application, and (if you're running a server) users that connect will invoke that same code that was already compiled when the server started.

Answer (score 7):

Node.js uses Google's V8 javascript engine which does compile all the javascript to native code.

Comment: And there is no need for this. Node.js is already pretty pretty fast, while PHP is known to be quite slow.

Comment: @Andrei According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)): native.

Comment: more information could be found here: http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot compile Node.js into native code. But you can write parts of your application in c++ using v8. But beware, the transition time of changing from js to c++ world is big.

You can also try to get the intermediate compilation from v8. But I haven't seen anybody doing that.

Comment: In most cases it's far easier and less error-prone to create a command-line tool and pipe to it via a subprocess.